# Is there a way to use a script to pull a date from a Google Form submission from sheets into Gmail?

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, google-forms

I have no experience with script writing, but I was able to find a script and edit it (with lots of trial and error) to fit my need.

I have a Google Form where the first question allows users to select a date, but it is not necessarily the date users are completing the form. The results export to a Google Sheet, and I have a script that sends an email with the form responses.

It worked beautifully until Daylight Savings Time. Now, the dates in the spreadsheet are correct, but in the emails they are one day off.

Example email message:

> Your child, NAME, received a dress code violation on Wed Mar 27 2019
>   23:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), for No ID.

Before Daylight Savings Time, the time was showing as `00:00:00`.

In the code, row[2] is the date pulled from the spreadsheet.

```
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function sendEmails2() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Script");
var startRow = 2;
var numRows = 5000;
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5000)
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
var row = data[i];
var emailAddress = row[12];
var message = "Your child, " + row[10] + ", received a dress code violation on " + row[2] + ", for " + row[11] + ".\nIf you have any questions, please email NAME at name.name@name.org\n\nThank you,\n\nNAME\nAssistant Principal";
var emailSent = row[13];
if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {
var subject = "Uniform Violation - Do Not Reply";
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 14).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    } 
  }
 }
```

Ideally, the email would provide the date exactly from the spreadsheet in `MM/DD/YYYY` format.

Instead, the emails show the previous day with the time of 11 pm.

Comment: Is the timezone for the script and spreadsheet the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function sendEmails2() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();//added this
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Script");
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = 5000;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5000)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[12];
    var message = "Your child, " + row[10] + ", received a dress code violation on " + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[2]),ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss" ) + ", for " + row[11] + ".\nIf you have any questions, please email NAME at name.name@name.org\n\nThank you,\n\nNAME\nAssistant Principal";//modified this
    var emailSent = row[13];
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {
      var subject = "Uniform Violation - Do Not Reply";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 14).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    } 
  }
}
```

You will probably have to change the dates format.

- [Date Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)